# Add jQuery on laravel 5.4 mix

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm already familiar with laravel 5.1 mix (elixir), and recently I decided to test laravel 5.4 mix.

I mixed my libs on vendors files.

```
mix
.styles([
    './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    './node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
], 'public/css/vendor.css')
.js([
    './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
], 'public/js/vendor.js')
.disableNotifications()
.version();
```

And included vendor on my page.

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.js') }}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
```

But, when I want use jQuery I have this error on image below. Before, in the laravel 5.1 I did exactly that way.

[image]

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just uncomment this line in your `assets/js/bootstrap.js` file:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

And make sure to require the bootstrap file in your `assets/js/app.js` like this:

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

Answer (score 9):

```
mix.autoload({ 'jquery': ['window.$', 'window.jQuery'] })
```

I had to add this to my webpack.mix.js

Comment: For it to work, your resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js must be required. and the following line must be present in it.
'window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');'

Comment: IMO this is the correct answer. The array is a list of variables that will have to match exactly in order for Webpack to include the module on the file that it's called. For example, Bootstrap won't work with the array in the answer because Bootstrap checks for the variable `jQuery` (`window.jQuery` isn't the same as `jQuery`, it has to be exact); adding `jQuery` to the array will make Bootstrap work.

Comment: `mix.autoload` is definitely the better way here since we dealing with web pack wrapped by laravel-mix

Answer (score 2):

The solution using laravel mix is force all modules to use the same jquery version: 
This is my code at top of webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
             'jquery': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/src/jquery')
        }
    }
});
```